# Autonomous Navigation of a Known Map with TurtleBot

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm following the tutorials on autonomous navigation of a turtlebot:

wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map

So, I run these commands on different terminals:

1- roscore

2- roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

3- roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/AddressToMap

I receive these messages:

([ WARN] [1405632943.683405903]: Waiting on transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: [ INFO] [1405632945.899453434]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

4- roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch --screen

Instead of TurtleBot a white circle appears in rviz, and there are red error signs beside GlobalStatus and RobotModel

My laptop runs Ubuntu 12.04, and ROS Hydro. No real robot is involved, I'm just trying to test the simulated turtlebot on my laptop.

EDIT: For using the turtlebot in simulation mode, the following link helped to solve my problem:

wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186970/autonomous-navigation-of-a-known-map-with-turtlebot/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you **don't actually have the real robot** the turtlebot_bringup **will fail** (you can see one of the errors from OpenNI trying to connect to a Kinect device that is not present: *[ INFO] [1405632945.899453434]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected*

If you want **to simulate** the **turtlebot install** the **package *ros-hydro-turtlebot-simulator***

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-07-17**:
ros-hydro-turtlebot-simulator is already installed on my machine. Should i use a different command than roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch to launch the turtlebot in simulation mode?